# methods in template: one works, one does not instantiate

Tags: c++, templates

```
 template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
 class svector {
 public:
     typedef T value_type;
     class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,T> {
     // ...
     };
 // ...
 svector::iterator insert( svector::iterator position, const T& val );
 void insert( svector::iterator position, size_t n, const T& val );
 svector::iterator erase( svector::iterator position );
 svector::iterator erase( svector::iterator first, svector::iterator last );
 // ...
 };

 template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
 class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator svector<T,MAXSIZE>::insert (class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator position, const T& val){
     insert( position, 1, val );
     return position;
 }

 template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
 void svector<T,MAXSIZE>::insert (class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator position, size_t n, const T& val){
     // ...
 }

 template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
 class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator ??????????????????????????????erase (class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator position){
     return erase( position, position );  // (1)
 }

 template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
 class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator ??????????????????????????????erase (class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator first,
                                           class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator last) {
     // ..
 }
```

The `insert` methods have been tested. But the very similar `erase` methods
are unwilling, and I fail to see why. Here's a UT-snippet:

```
typedef class util::svector<int, 10> vecIntX;
vecIntX v1;
for( int e = 0; e < 10; e++ ) v1.push_back( e );
vecIntX::iterator it = v1.begin();
v1.erase( it );   // (2)
```

Eclipse complains at line (1):

```
"Invalid arguments, candidates are ? erase(?), ? erase(?,?)
```

Error during linking at line (2):

```
undefined reference to 'util::svector<int, 10>::erase(util::svector<int, 10>::iterator)'
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter The original text was good. Eclipse complains at line (1), but the other error is from ld.

Comment: Sorry, that bit was unclear. I edited because the lack of code formatting was erasing everything between angle brackets. Feel free to edit again, but please check the preview (as always).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the method definitions with the class name:

```
template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
class svector { ... };

template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator svector<T,MAXSIZE>::erase(
    class svector<T,MAXSIZE>::iterator position){ ... }
```

when you inline the methods outside of the class.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it too, after posting. Too many decorations around for my old eyes.

Comment: @laune also in the method arguments, you don't need to prefix with the type. As in `template <...> class svector<...>::iterator svector<...>::erase(iterator position) { ... }`. Cheers.

Comment: Woops, never mind my previous comment. This is a valid usage of the `class` keyword.

Comment: @Potatoswatter iterator seems to work, though. Also, I can use `class` in those places, works fine - OK just saw your last comment.