# type-dependent nested-name-specifier in elaborated-type-specifier

Tags: c++, templates, elaborated-type-specifier

I never saw a nested-name-specifier in an elaborated-type-specifier before [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21952375/153285), and at first glance I thought it wasn't even covered by the grammar. Now I see that since C++98 up to the present, it's translated as a special case without the *typename-specifier* construct. C++11 7.1.6.3/2 (7.1.5.3/2 in C++98):

> 3.4.4 describes how name lookup proceeds for the *identifier* in an *elaborated-type-specifier*. If the *identifier* resolves to a *class-name* or *enum-name*, the *elaborated-type-specifier* introduces it into the declaration the same way a *simple-type-specifier* introduces its *type-name*.

Therefore it would seem that although you can form a qualified elaborated-type-specifier, you need to take care that it's never type-dependent. Name resolution per 3.4.4 at template definition time will never find a class-name because dependent names are presumed to be objects unless prefixed with the `typename` keyword, which isn't grammatically allowed in this context.

Is this an accurate assessment of the meaning of the standard, and the design intent of the language?

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem if it's type-dependent, so long as the lookup happens at the point of instantiation. This is what clang implements, which is why it allows `struct S1<T>::I` yet diagnoses `struct S2<T>::I` as an error in http://ideone.com/paV3Kh (note: ideone uses GCC, and GCC allows this, so you don't see the error there)

Comment: @hvd Interesting, and strange; thanks! But really what I'm wondering about is why the `typename` keyword isn't required. Actually I haven't yet looked up the list of exceptions where it's not required, so I'll go do that now…

Comment: Good point. Quoting 14.6p2: "A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a *template-parameter* is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
by the keyword `typename`." I don't see an exception that would allow `struct S1<T>::I` either.

Comment: Ah! 14.6p5: "A qualified name used as the name in a *mem-initializer-id*, a *base-specifier*, or an *elaborated-type-specifier* is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. In a *nested-name-specifier*
that immediately contains a *nested-name-specifier* that depends on a template parameter, the *identifier* or *simple-template-id* is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding from the comments:

Take this program as an example:

```
template <typename T>
struct S1 { struct I { }; };

template <typename T>
struct S2 { typedef struct S1<T>::I I; }; // okay

template <typename T>
struct S3 { typedef struct S2<T>::I I; }; // okay at definition time
                                          // usually error at instantiation time
template <>
struct S2<short> : S1<short> { };

int main() {
  S1<int>::I a;
  S2<int>::I &b = a; // okay
  S3<int>::I &c = b; // error
  S1<short>::I d;
  S2<short>::I &e = d; // okay
  S3<short>::I &f = e; // okay
}
```

At template definition time, both `S2` and `S3` are okay: 14.6p5 lists the exceptions where `typename` is not required. Essentially: where the use is unambiguous because the name can never be anything other than a type, `typename` is not required. This includes several cases where `typename` is not syntactically allowed, so where requiring `typename` would mean there is no way to write the program. Both `typename struct S<T>::I` and `struct typename S<T>::I` are hard errors, and `struct S<T>::I` is unambiguous.

At template instantiation time, the rules of 3.4.4 are clearer: both `struct S1<int>::I` and `struct S2<int>::I` can then be found, where it becomes apparent that `S2<int>::I` is a typedef, so `struct S2<int>::I` is an error. At the same time, at that point, `S2<short>::I` is seen not to be a typedef, but a struct, so `struct S2<short>::I` is allowed.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience; this question was just a result of my faulty memory, and I would have posted an answer a while ago but my internet connection went out :P

Comment: @Potatoswatter I didn't know this, so for my own knowledge of C++, it's good that you asked. :)